# Requests python

Tags: python, requests

Если делаю какие то запросы на сайт, провайдер как я понял получает данные о том, куда я давал эти запросы. Мне достаточно включить VPN в браузере, или установить отдельное приложение? Или Прокси сервер себе взять?

Comment: Тогда провайдер VPN или провайдер прокси будут знать, куда вы даёте запросы

Comment: Браузер просировать нет смысла, `requests` с ним никак не связан. Если `selenium` — то да, ставьте в браузер. Чтобы весь трафик шёл через VPN, нужен openVPN, WireGuard, 1.1.1.1, разные варианты. Но прокси можно и в requests указать.

Comment: VPN скроет от провайдера откуда вы делаете запросы, но сами запросы все равно сможет отследить.